# Is it possible to recover the source code of a nuget package built with EmbedAllSources enabled?

Tags: .net, debugging, nuget, csproj, pdb-files

I am building a nuget package from a [new-format-csproj](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) project. I included the [EmbedAllSources](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/tree/master/docs#embedallsources) property (see below) in my csproj file:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Omitted for brevity --> 
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
  <EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
  <!-- Omitted for brevity --> 
</PropertyGroup>
...
```

Is it possible that consumers of my nuget, retrieve/reconstruct the source code of my nuget because of that property? If so, how?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you may want to take a look at a .NET Decompiler. I tend to use ILSpy because it works well and is free.  I use it to confirm what is visible in my compiled applications before releasing them.  https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy

Comment: I'm not asking about the decompilation of code using tools like ILSpy. I am asking rather about the impact of that property on the content of the *.pdb file and whether I can get the source code from it. Thanks for the link anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Running this with dotnet core 3.1.201 and a minimal test project, I end up with a `.nupkg` and a `.symbols.nupkg` in the output folder. These files are just zips, so unzip them in any way you like. The `.symbols.nupkg` file contains the `.pdb` file under `/libs/{framework}/`. I didn't even try to do anything clever... just chucked it into notepad++ and you can see clearly that all the relevant source is in there. Extracting it into individual `.cs` files will take a bit more effort, but not too much more.